# Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, parse-platform

I have a question about CoreData and RESTful web service.
I read this tutorial [How To Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service – Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1) about the synchronization of local CoreData and remote data.
I can not understand because in the method:

```
- (void)downloadDataForRegisteredObjects:(BOOL)useUpdatedAtDate
```

the information are always saved before on JSON files

(using the method:   `[self writeJSONResponse:responseObject toDiskForClassWithName:className];` )

When all operations are completed then it's possible to store these on CoreData.

Are there some underlying motivation for this?

Why we can't  save directly on CoreData to delete the overhead added from read / write to files?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr this save to disk is probably unnecessary overhead.

I can't comment on the author's motivations but I suspect it's because the app is built as a tutorial so the save to file is to separate the section on downloading data from Parse.com and the section on parsing JSON into CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to write the JSON files out before applying values to managed objects (and, if you do write JSON files out, even to the caches directory, you should remove them when done).

Here is how you can apply JSON data from a web service response to a Core Data managed object.

The article uses AFHTTPRequestOperation, so we'll use that here. Note that I'm assuming you have some way of getting the managed object you are applying the JSON data to. Normally this would be done using the [find-or-create](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) pattern.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[SDAFParseAPIClient sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (json != nil && [json respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]){
            // Set the JSON values on the managed object, assuming the managed object properties map directly to the JSON keys
            [managedObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:json];
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Request for class %@ failed with error: %@", className, error);
    }];
```

The SDAFParseAPIClient, I assume, already parses the JSON. We check to make sure that the parsed JSON is an `NSDictionary`, and then use [Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) to apply it to the managed object.

Doing the same thing using `NSURLConnection` is straightforward, and probably a better learning experience. The other Foundation networking methods (`NSURLSession`, etc.) would work much the same way:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completion:(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)]
    NSIndexSet          *acceptableStatusCodes  =  [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(200, 99)];

    if ([acceptableStatusCodes containsIndex:[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]]){
        if ([data length] > 0){
            // Parse the JSON
            id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
            if (json != nil && [json respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]){
                // Set the JSON values on the managed object, assuming the managed object properties map directly to the JSON keys
                [managedObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:json];
            } else {
                // handle the error
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Handle the error
    }
}];
```

We send an asynchronous request with a completion block. The block is passed an `NSHTTPURLResponse`, `NSData`, and `NSError`. First, we check that the `statusCode` of the response is in the 200 'OK' range. If it's not, or if the response is nil, we probably have been passed an NSError that describes why. If the response IS in the 200 range, we make sure the NSData has something in it before handing it to `NSJSONSerialization`. Once the JSON object has been parsed, we make sure it's responds to the relevant `NSDictionary` methods, and then use Key Value Coding to apply the values to the managed object. This assumes that the JSON keys and values map directly to the properties of the managed object - if they do not, you have a number of options for remapping or transforming keys and values which are even further beyond the scope of this question.